# Need a query where list doesn't contain an item of another list

Tags: c#, .net, parse-platform

I have a local list with ParseUsers (localPlayers) and a list with ParseUsers in my ParseObject (remoteGame). I want to find all objects which don't contain any of the players in the local list of ParseUsers.

Until now I tried three different options which didn't work:

1:

```
ParseQuery<ParseGame> query = from remoteGame in new ParseQuery<ParseGame>()
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Any(x => localPlayers.Contains(x))
                              select remoteGame;
```

2:

```
ParseQuery<ParseGame> query = from remoteGame in new ParseQuery<ParseGame>()
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Intersect(localPlayers).Any()
                              select remoteGame;
```

3:

```
ParseQuery<ParseGame> query = from remoteGame in new ParseQuery<ParseGame>()
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Contains(localPlayers[0])
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Contains(localPlayers[1])
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Contains(localPlayers[2])
                              where !remoteGame.Players.Contains(localPlayers[3])
                              select remoteGame;
```

Option 1 and 2 give an exeception that the query isn't supported and option 3 gives an exception that a query can't have multiple constraints for one key.

Appreciating your help,
hig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying I have found a solution. I think the documentation on parse.com is not quite right. It says:

> If you want to retrieve objects that do not match any of several values you can use WhereNotContainedIn or a !Contains LINQ query, providing an list of acceptable values.

But in reality you can't provide a list of acceptable values in a !Contains Linq query, rather a single value, whereas you can provide a list of acceptable values using WhereNotContainedIn.

So the solution looks like this:

```
ParseQuery<ParseGame> query = from remoteGame in new ParseQuery<ParseGame>()
                              select remoteGame;
query = query.WhereNotContainedIn("Players", localPlayers);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
remoteGame.Players.Except(localPlayers)
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I can't use this in a ParseQuery.

Comment: Yes, but ParseQuery isn't my own class. It's from the Parse SDK (http://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseQuery_1.htm)